# set header in Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

i want to pass custom header in Alamofire.

```
[String : AnyObjetc]
```

I have surfed a lot on internet but fails to get the answer.

all the solutions are `[String : String]`

```
let headers = [
        "Authorization": "Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==",
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    ]
```

I want to pass like

```
let Header = [
    "ActorImageDetails" : [    
        "TokenId":"bwymina009aEMyCknQHi87B2r0RNhffnrj8sXayGt1OSWsRmj2+daw==",
        "UserId":"400295",
        "AppId":"1"
     ]
]
```

Comment: You need to say what is wrong for people to help.

Comment: Heads up. Headers are strings, and `String` is compatible with `AnyObject`, so your code is ok.

Comment: i need like [String : AnyObject]

Comment: Take a look on my comment

Comment: Any Answers For Custom Headers: as I need to pass int in the header @ZetrixWeb

Answer (score 1):

Use the NSMutableURLRequest method `setValue:ForHTTPHeaderField` e.g.:

```
yourRequest.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add headers for request use:

```
let url = NSURL(string: Constants.Connector.UrlAddress)
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!.URLByAppendingPathComponent(path))
request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.addValue("Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
```

> I want to pass like
>
> [...]

You shouldn't pass your data in headers. You should use `NSURLRequest.HTTPBody` like:

```
let json: [String: AnyObject] = [...]
let data: NSData = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(json, options: .allZeros, error: nil)

request.HTTPBody = data
```

Confirm it with your backend support